# How can I run a command with grunt-shell with elevated privileges?

Tags: powershell, gruntjs

I need to run a PowerShell using Grunt. This means I will, in many cases, need to set a less restrictive execution policy so that the script can run. I believe I can do this with `reg add`, but I can't run *that* without administrator privileges. Any way to do this with the [grunt-shell plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the execution policy when calling powershell?

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "d:\test.ps1"
```

Doing it this way admin privileges aren't required